# How To Get Copy of Bitcoin Source Code

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, open-source

Does anyone have an idea of where can I find a copy of the bitcoin source code. I mean doesn't it supposed to be open source, where is the open source project for bitcoin so I can read the code.

Answer (score 8):

[bitcoind](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind) is what is most widely used. And here is the source: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/

But there's various other implementations for clients such as BitcoinJ for Java https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/ or http://libbitcoin.dyne.org/ for C++.

However, for miners the story is a bit different. If you're a miner you kind of need to use bitcoind. Otherwise bad things might happen such as the blockchain fork from last March: http://bitcoinmagazine.com/3668/bitcoin-network-shaken-by-blockchain-fork/

---

There is also helpful documentation such as the [detailed Bitcoin spec for the P2P layer](https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/p2p_network.html) at bitcoin.org.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect, bitcoind 8.1 fixed the fork issue: http://bitcoin.org/en/alert/2013-03-15-upgrade-deadline

Miners should be able to use the latest 8.5 code unless they have a specific dependency on/for an older version.